# Return div as a string- but only visible parts

Tags: jquery, html

There is a div `#allContent` that contains a few divs within it. I would like to return the entire `#allContent` as a string, but remove any divs contained inside that are not visible.

I imagine this can probably be accomplished with some combination of `filter()`, `:visible`, and `contents()`, but I can't figure out exactly how to do it.

Comment: Do you want the HTML markup, or just the text content?

Comment: is there a container for div#allContent?

Comment: @Ehtesham- the div#allContent is the container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var clone = $('#allContent').clone()
                            .appendTo('body')
                            .find(':hidden')
                            .remove()
                            .end()
                            .remove();

var content = clone[0].outerHTML || $('<div>').append(clone).html();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ChXPB/3/

**EDIT:** Changed it to include the outerHTML div.

**EDIT:** Made it mostly chained, and repaired the Firefox shim.

---

*Seems that we need to temporarily add the clone to the DOM.*

<s>This should do it:</s>

```
$('#allContent').clone().find(':hidden').remove().end().html();
```

Comment: if there's a parent container exist for div#allContent, we don't need to append it to body?

Comment: @Ehtesham: Yeah, I wasn't sure at first if that should be included, but it seems that it should, so I just updated to use `outerHTML` with a Firefox fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
var allContentsHtml = '';
$('#allContent div:visible')
        .each(function() { 
                   allContentsHtml += $(this).html(); 
                   }
              );

$('#output').html(allContentsHtml );
```

Comment: Something like `<div>a<div>b</div>c</div>` will become `acb`